# Passthrough proxy to a different IP address

Tags: linux, nginx, proxy, dns, reverse-proxy

We run a multi site platform and customers configure their domains to point to our entry server IP for domain routing using an A record.

We are looking at migrating to a whole new setup that's more scalable.

However we don't have the ability to control everyone's DNS settings.

How can we setup a passthrough proxy or reverse proxy on our ubuntu box? Maybe Nginx? We currently have apache running.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Run DNS server on your ubuntu box and rewrite A records for domains you want to point to new server. I am using DNS manager software from ispSystems for the same reason.